# Counterexample to statement regarding factors

Tags: factoring

I've been struggling for an inordinate amount of time to come up with a counterexample to this statement but with no luck. Any help would be great thanks.

Suppose that $a^2|bc$. Then $a|b$ or $a|c$.

Comment: Try $a=10{{}}$.

Comment: ah thanks, got one when b=8 and c=25